# Swift: How to determine object type based on the outcome of switch statement

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have a function that returns whether an item exists in 1 of 3 CoreData entities, depending on the `list: CoreDataList enum` argument passed to that function:

```
        static func listContains(word: String, list: CoreDataList) -> Bool {
        var reply = false
        
        switch list {
        case .itemsSearched:
            let request : NSFetchRequest<ItemsSearched> = ItemsSearched.fetchRequest()
        case .itemsAdded:
            let request : NSFetchRequest<ItemsAdded> = ItemsAdded.fetchRequest()
        case .itemsFinished:
            let request : NSFetchRequest<ItemsFinished> = ItemsFinished.fetchRequest()
        }
    
        do {
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "item == %@", word)
            let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(request)
            if fetchedResults.count == 1 {
                reply = true
            }
        } catch {
            print ("fetch task failed", error)
        }
        return reply
    }
```

The problem here is that `let request` cannot be initialized before the switch statement because its type will depend on the outcome of the switch.

Therefore I cannot find a way to do this function without repeating the entire `do catch block` for each case, which will result in repeating the same code three times. The other option is to separate into three different function, but this presents the same code repetition problem.

Comment: Define the fetch request before the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a generic function for this

```
static func checkCount<T: NSManagedObject>(word: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext, type: T.Type) -> Bool {
    let request = T.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "item == %@", word)
    do {
        let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(request)
        if fetchedResults.count == 1 {
            return true
        }
    } catch {
        print ("fetch task failed", error)
    }
    return false
}
```

and then call it from inside the `switch`

```
case .itemsSearched:
    return checkCount(word: word, context: context, type: ItemsSearched.self)
```

Note that I added context as a parameter to the function since I didn't know how it is declared, perhaps that parameter isn't needed.

Comment: If I use the 'context' global variable which is declared in the class scope, the app crashed when it reaches the first line in the 'do' block. I have to pass 'context' as an argument like you did, or declare another 'context' variable inside the function body for this to work. Any idea why?

Comment: Could it be nil? Actually it is not a bad idea to send the context as an argument, it makes the code more future proof if you decide to change how to access your managed object context.